# overlap divs for ngif else Angular4

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm subscribed to an stream to get some data from a third party API and while that's happening I display a div with a spinning wheel kind of stuff. Once I have the data then that data is replacing that div. I have that with an `ngif else`:

```
<div *ngIf="my-data;else loading" class="my-data-container">
  ...
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
   <div class="loading-container">
      shows the loading spinning wheel    
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

the problem I have is that for a really short period of time both divs appear on the screen and they make an strange effect like a small blip. I would like them to overlap each other otherwise they appear one under the other. Can I achieve that via code or do I need to investigate a css trick for it?

Comment: How do you initialise my-data?

Comment: I do that via a subscription to an observable on the ngOnInit method:
ngOnInit() {
this.myDataService.get()
                     .subscribe(g => { this.my-data = g });
}

Comment: Move the div content to an other ng-template and add then option on ngIf. I can post my suggestion if you wish

Comment: if you don't mind, paste the example because I have tried both the ng-container from the answer below and your ng-template option with then and I still get both elements at some point in the screen

Comment: Actually both solutions worked (as well as mine one). The problem was a position: absolute missing in one of the containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare `my-data` value as `null` at the start and change `ngIf` syntax to use `then`:

```
<div *ngIf="my-data; then #content; else loading" class="my-data-container">
</div>
<ng-template #content>
    show this content after loading
</ng-template
<ng-template #loading>
   <div class="loading-container">
      shows the loading spinning wheel    
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use container as ngif template instead of div it self

```
<ng-container *ngIf="my-data;else loading">
  <div class="my-data-container">
  ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
   <div class="loading-container">
      shows the loading spinning wheel    
   </div>
</ng-template>
```